# Why is CPSR not a banked register?

Tags: assembly, arm

In ARM, the SPSR is a banked register i.e. after every change in mode, CPSR is copied into the SPSR, and after the mode returns, the SPSR is copied back to CPSR. Why is the CPSR not banked directly? It seems like there are two additional instructions with every mode change (copy into spsr, copy into cpsr)

Comment: not really instructions, copying the data back and forth, the architecture if you could look at it may not have any cost at all, banking would be a cost of more flip flops.  Arms are not microcoded so this copy takes no time, one of the clock cycles dealing with the interrupt/event can also in parallel save the cpsr.  Likewise on the return.  Basically a bank switch and a copy of the cpsr take the same exact amount of time.  One clock edge with a little setup time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual mode changes are not an efficiency goal on the **ARM**.  Typically, *manual mode* changes are only done to setup stacks, etc at boot or initialization time.

The `cpsr` is the *active* copy.  Why do we have a banked `lr` register but not the current `pc`?  The `spsr` is a **banked** `cpsr` for a different mode; just like the banked `lr` is the `pc` for a different mode.  The **banking** is so that the exception state can be transparent.  The `spsr` is banked as an *interrupt* or *data abort* may occur in any mode; we need to save it so that we **stack** execution correctly.  The normal *unbanked* user mode never stacks with another mode.  *mode* changes are done automatically in *exception conditions*.

The mode registers are setup to make *exception handling* very efficient and flexible.  *Manual mode* changes are not highly convenient as they are not normally used.  You can copy any banked register to an un-banked one before switching modes so that the state can be transferred between the two; this is common when *system* mode is used for all *exception handling*.  In this case, the registers are often stored to a *task context block* by the kernel and this is not an efficiency issue as there are *memory stores* that will pipeline.

Comment: In the *system mode* case, the *exception* `sp` may be used as a general purpose register.  The destination *system mode* contains a real *stack* which often includes a *task control block* via a mask.  The last part is common to many OS designs, not specific to the **ARM**.